# what is the proper way to arrange a project in android studio?

Tags: android, structure, project

i am working on an android project and want to arrange my java classes into folders. eg. a folder for activity and another folder for fragments etc.

Can anyone tell me what is the standard way of doing it or give me any link to a sample project ? thanks

Comment: Don't do that.  Unless it's a separate component of your project, put them all in one folder.  Keep in mind separate folders means separate packages, so for the most part, all Fragments and Activities for each component should live in the same folder.

Comment: wouldn't that make the code unfathomable? if i'm correct breaking it down to smaller components enhances readability of the code. Imagine you project having 300 classes then what?

Comment: If you have over 300 Activities/Fragments, then the architecture is wrong.  Keep in mind that you can re-use Activities and Fragments and have them run in different "modes" for similar but different uses.  You can also put utility classes in a separate folder in order to minimize code duplication.  I've worked on some very large scale production Android projects (over 70,000 lines of code), and while we may have separate folders for different components, all related Activities and Fragments for each component live in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link which provides the android best practices - [Android best practices](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices). This link has additional information that will be useful during android application development.